# Is it possible to generate C# files using protobuf-net for proto2 files with extension of 'FieldOptions'?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net, protogen

I have a proto file with proto2 syntax. I am trying to auto-generate C# file using the protogen. Although I can generate the file without any errors, I get an error while building the project (the C# file is part of a .Net 5 project in Visual Studio). The error looks like :

> error CS0400: The type or namespace name 'Google' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I have added the *'descriptor.proto'* in the correct path but it does not seem to make any difference in how protogen auto-generates the C# file.

*myproto.proto*

```
syntax = "proto2";

import "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto";

package test;

extend google.protobuf.FieldOptions {
  optional string sampleValue = 50004;
}

message TestMessage {
  required string id = 1;
  optional float value = 2;
  optional string sample_val = 3;
}
```

*myproto.cs*

```
// <auto-generated>
//   This file was generated by a tool; you should avoid making direct changes.
//   Consider using 'partial classes' to extend these types
//   Input: myproto.proto
// </auto-generated>

#region Designer generated code
#pragma warning disable CS0612, CS0618, CS1591, CS3021, IDE0079, IDE1006, RCS1036, RCS1057, RCS1085, RCS1192
namespace Test
{

    [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoContract()]
    public partial class TestMessage : global::ProtoBuf.IExtensible
    {
        private global::ProtoBuf.IExtension __pbn__extensionData;
        global::ProtoBuf.IExtension global::ProtoBuf.IExtensible.GetExtensionObject(bool createIfMissing)
            => global::ProtoBuf.Extensible.GetExtensionObject(ref __pbn__extensionData, createIfMissing);

        [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1, Name = @"id", IsRequired = true)]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(2, Name = @"value")]
        public float Value
        {
            get => __pbn__Value.GetValueOrDefault();
            set => __pbn__Value = value;
        }
        public bool ShouldSerializeValue() => __pbn__Value != null;
        public void ResetValue() => __pbn__Value = null;
        private float? __pbn__Value;

        [global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(3, Name = @"sample_val")]
        [global::System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue("")]
        public string SampleVal
        {
            get => __pbn__SampleVal ?? "";
            set => __pbn__SampleVal = value;
        }
        public bool ShouldSerializeSampleVal() => __pbn__SampleVal != null;
        public void ResetSampleVal() => __pbn__SampleVal = null;
        private string __pbn__SampleVal;

    }

    public static partial class Extensions
    {
        public static string GetsampleValue(this global::Google.Protobuf.Reflection.FieldOptions obj)
            => obj == null ? default : global::ProtoBuf.Extensible.GetValue<string>(obj, 50004);

        public static void SetsampleValue(this global::Google.Protobuf.Reflection.FieldOptions obj, string value)
            => global::ProtoBuf.Extensible.AppendValue<string>(obj, 50004, value);

    }
}

#pragma warning restore CS0612, CS0618, CS1591, CS3021, IDE0079, IDE1006, RCS1036, RCS1057, RCS1085, RCS1192
#endregion
```

The error occurs in the static class `Extensions` for both methods in the generated 'myproto.cs'. Isn't it possible to use only the protobuf-net package without any additional Google packages? If not then which package do I have to add as additional dependency? I might be missing something trivial but I can't seem to understand as of now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No Google reference is needed here; you have *extended* `FieldOptions`, which is the *descriptor metadata type* that relates to fields. protobuf-net has an implementation of that in the protobuf-net.Reflection package, in exactly where this could be expected: `Google.Protobuf.Reflection.FieldOptions`.

However! I doubt that this is going to do what you expect. In this scenario, you have defined a "custom option". Custom options *aren't related to runtime instance data* - they are part of the .proto DSL, and are usually used *to influence code generation*; in your case, it would be something like:

```proto
  optional string sample_val = 3 [sampleValue= "ExtensionTypeName"];
```

(or something like that)

The point here is that the *value* (`"ExtensionTypeName"`) only applies when talking about the *schema field*, which is why it is dangling off of `FieldOptions` (which represents an *instance* of a schema field definition). It has nothing whatsoever to do with your `TestMessage` usage at runtime. Further: protobuf-net *does not currently package custom options into the generated C#* (it could do, presumably as a base-64 chunk in an attribute, or similar - it just doesn't currently).

So: taking this back a step: what does your extension `sampleValue` *mean to you*, and to what instances do you see it relating?

Comment: Ah the reflection package was the one that I was missing. Thank you! This should work for now. About the extensions and custom options, it looks a bit confusing to me so I will first do some more research before proceeding with it.